# MongoDB get whole document filtered by subdocuments content

Tags: mongodb

I have a simple structure with an array of subdocuments lie this:

```
{
    _id: xxxxx,
    referenceNumber: 1,
    participants: [
        {name: 'Alice', role: 'lead'},
        {name: 'Bob', role: 'support'}

    ]
},
{
    _id: yyyyy,
    referenceNumber: 2,
    participants: [
        {name: 'Alice', role: 'development'},
        {name: 'Bob', role: 'lead'}

    ]
},
{
    _id: zzzz,
    referenceNumber: 2,
    participants: [
        {name: 'Alice', role: 'lead'},
        {name: 'Bob', role: 'support'},
        {name: 'Charlie', role: 'development'}

    ]
}
```

And i now want all the entries where "Alice" is in the "lead" role.

so the desired result would be:

```
{
    _id: xxxxx,
    referenceNumber: 1,
    participants: [
        {name: 'Alice', role: 'lead'},
        {name: 'Bob', role: 'support'}

    ]
},
{
    _id: zzzz,
    referenceNumber: 2,
    participants: [
        {name: 'Alice', role: 'lead'},
        {name: 'Bob', role: 'support'},
        {name: 'Charlie', role: 'development'}

    ]
}
```

i tried `find({'patricipants.name': 'Alice', 'participants.role': 'lead'})`, which of course returns all documents where "Alice" is present and *someone* is in the "lead" role.

then i tried aggregate, with unwind:

```
aggregate(
    [
        { $unwind: '$participants'},
        { $match: {'participants.name': 'Alice', 'participants.role': 'lead'}}
    ]
)
```

which then just returns

```
 {
        _id: xxxxx,
        referenceNumber: 1,
        participants: [
            {name: 'Alice', role: 'lead'},
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: zzzz,
        referenceNumber: 2,
        participants: [
            {name: 'Alice', role: 'lead'},
        ]
    }
```

with all other `participants` missing, obviously as this is what `$unwind` does.

is there a way that saves me making a request for all the `_ids` found in `aggregate` to retrieve the whole documents?

Comment: Have you tried ? `db.collection.find( { "participants" : { $elemMatch : { "name": "Alice", "role": "lead" } } } )`  More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#array-of-embedded-documents

Comment: works, i seem to have confused query/elemMatch with projection/elemMatch https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/ - give as an answer please to is can accept

Comment: well, its the other way round, but quite the same

Comment: yeah that is the closest I can manage.